# Auto trigger click to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

Please can someone suggest how i can get this function to work without clicking the `<ul>` class ct-group ?

```
function triggerCTPartButtonClick(oUL) {

    try {

        optionalLog('man', 'triggerCTPartButtonClick');
        $(oUL).parent().parent().find("button.partselect").click();

    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex.message);
    }

}
```

When you click on below it loads the function, but i need it to auto load.

```
strGroup = gfCStr(objRs("Group"))
if strGroup <> "" then
    %><ul class="ct-group" onclick="triggerBootPartButtonClick(this);"><%
    strSplit = split(strGroup, ",")
    for intcount = 0 to ubound(strSplit)-1
       strItem = strSplit(intcount)
        if (strItem <> "") then
            %><li><%=strItem%></li><%
        end if
    next
    %></ul><%
end if
%>
```

Added code for button

```
                                      <button class="fixmed partselect" 

                                        data-ldLength = ""
                                        data-term1 = "<%=gfCStr(objRs("Term1"))%>"
                                        data-term2 = "<%=gfCStr(objRs("Term2"))%>"
                                        data-ldCPBoot = "<%=gfCStr(objRs("Boot1"))%>"
                                        data-ldDTBoot = "<%=gfCStr(objRs("Boot2"))%>"
                                        data-ldLeadQty = "1"
                                        data-ldQtyReq = "<%=gfCStr(objRs("QtyReq"))%>"
                                        data-ldLocation = ""

                                        data-place="vwcutlist" 
                                        data-docmode="<%=docmode%>" 
                                        data-docref="<%=docref%>" 
                                        data-part="<%=gfCStr(objRs("PartNo"))%>" 
                                        data-wo="<%=gfCStr(objRs("Works"))%>" 
                                        data-tray="<%=gfCStr(objRs("Tra"))%>" 
                                        data-cable="<%=gfCStr(objRs("Cabl"))%>" 

                                        onclick="selectListPart(this, 'vwwo');"><%=gfCStr(objRs("PartNo"))%>
                                         </button>
```

…..Edit 02.03.2020.....

Tried the below code - I get the alert, but the button still doesn't click as when clicking from the UL.

```
           (function () {
try {
alert('hello')
    optionalLog('man', 'triggerCTPartButtonClick');
    $("button.partselect").click();
 } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
   }     
  } 
)();
</script>
```

Comment: You can try to change that function to an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) and remove the inline click handler.

Answer (score 0):

First I what I would do is change "button.partselect" and give "id" to this element and modify the query to find this id.

After you can remove parameter "oUL" from function and "this" reference to object itself at the and as @volt mention use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
(function () {
try {
    optionalLog('man', 'triggerCTPartButtonClick');
    $("button.partselect").click();
 } catch (ex) {
    console.log(ex.message);
   }     
  } 
})();
```

I think something like this should work

Comment: Are you able to give an example ? I have added sample button code.

Comment: Try this or something like this

Comment: I have tried adding the code in <script> tags underneath where the UL loads the button, but its not triggering. Tried adding alert("hello"); after the try{ but the alert isn't triggering either. Any idea?

Comment: Possibly Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'

Comment: Get the alert now, but button doesn't click

Comment: Well the question is where the button is located to localize this button it has to be rendered before the script is called